# Using ParamSpec with Protocol instead of with Callable in Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

In the following code, I define a function type using either `Protocol` or `Callable`.

*mypy* complains about my use of `Protocol`. I added *mypy*'s error as a comment directly in the code.

*Pylance* finds no errors.

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Callable, Concatenate

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R', covariant=True)

class FuncType(Protocol[P, R]):
    def __call__(self, x: int, s: str,
                 *args: P.args, **kw_args: P.kwargs) -> R: ...

def forwarder1(fp: FuncType[P, R], *args: P.args, **kw_args: P.kwargs) -> R:
    return fp(0, '', *args, **kw_args)

def forwarder2(fp: Callable[Concatenate[int, str, P], R],
               *args: P.args, **kw_args: P.kwargs) -> R:
    return fp(0, '', *args, **kw_args)

def my_f(x: int, s: str, d: float) -> str:
    return f"{x}, {s}, {d}"

# Argument 1 to "forwarder1" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, str, float], str]";
#   expected "FuncType[<nothing>, <nothing>]"
# Argument 2 to "forwarder1" has incompatible type "float";
#   expected <nothing>
forwarder1(my_f, 1.2)

# no errors here
forwarder2(my_f, 1.2)
```

Have I come across a bug in *mypy*, or is there really something wrong with my use of `Protocol`?

Comment: Your usage looks perfectly valid. Also this example typechecks cleanly with Pyright. Probably you've hit a `mypy` bug. This is a typevar inference failure, and I can't find an open issue for this problem. Consider reporting at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike I sent the [bug report](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15734).

Comment: Awesome! Please post both code and playground - this will make issue easier to search later and to look through quickly without visiting external links.